# Need help visualizing an n-braid formed by connecting punctured planes with strings

Tags: braid-groups

---

I was reading Princeton companion and I got the following at page no.160
Take two parallel planes, each punctured at n points.

> "Label the holes 1 to n in each plane, and run a string
> from each hole in the first plane to one in the second,
> in such a way that no two strings go to the same hole.
> The result is an n-braid".

I'm having trouble visualizing the concept of an n-braid formed by connecting two parallel planes, each punctured at n points, with strings. Specifically, I'm struggling to understand how to interpret the diagrams provided in the text. Can someone help explain the process of creating an n-braid and provide insights into how to visualize it effectively? Additionally, how can we ensure that the strings go from left to right without "doubling back," as mentioned in the description? Any assistance or clarification on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

---